# Fill an empty stack with numbers from other k stacks such that sum of squared distance between adjacent numbers in new stack is minimized

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, stack

There are k stacks already filled with numbers with range[0,5]. I need to fill an empty stack by popping the numbers from other k stacks and pushing them to this stack. I need to do it in such a way that sum of squared distance between all adjacent numbers in this new stack is minimized. Note that size of each of the filled stack is around 100 times smaller than k

Example: lets consider k=3 filled stacks, s1=[1,2], s2=[3,4], s3=[4,5] with their 'top' part at extreme left. Now if I push numbers into some empty stack E=[] from S1, S2, S3 in following order:
*pop s1, pop s1, pop s2, pop s2, pop s3, pop s3*
I get E=[5,4,4,3,2,1] with sum of squared distance for all adjacent numbers = (5-4)^2 + (4-4)^2 +(4-3)^2 +(3-2)^2 +(2-1)^2 = 1+0+1+1+1 = 4. Hence its cost is 4 which seems minimum if done in this particular order. Therefore the solution is
*order(pop s1, pop s1, pop s2, pop s2, pop s3, pop s3)*

My Incorrect Approach:
Consider the set of numbers at the top of k stacks. Find the minimum number and push it to new stack. Do it repeatedly until all k stacks become empty. Data Structure used: Priority Queue. Time Complexity: O(S*log(k)) where S is the size of each stack.
I have 2 questions.
1. What do you think is the most efficient way to do it correctly? 
2. What do you think is the most efficient way to do it approximately(better than mine approach in terms of correctness)?

Comment: Please provide an example of stacks and your expected result.

Comment: If this is a practical task, needed just join contains of all stack together, and sort it thereafter.

Comment: I see, in you example all 3 input stacks are sorted. Is this input data property (stack is sorted), or just a "bug in example"?

Comment: @olegarch Hi, as soon as you pop the element from pre filled stacks=(s1,s2...), it gets push into the empty stack E. Therefore you cant just pop the numbers and join them and sort them before pushing them into empty stack E

Comment: @olegarch no its not input data property, i just used that to simplify my solution to the question

Comment: @Aldert i added the simple example.